# Issue with Tempo Slider - Drum Sequencer Obj - C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

I am creating a simple drum machine. This function controls the time between each sample that is played (thus controlling the tempo of the drum machine). I need to control the tempo with a slider, so I'm hoping to be able to control the 'time duration until next step' value with this if possible. However, when I have tried to do this, it tells me "time is part of NSDate"

```
-(void)run
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        // get current time
        NSDate* time = [NSDate date];

        // keeping going around the while loop if the sequencer is running
        while (self.running)
        {
            // sleep until the next step is due
            [NSThread sleepUntilDate:time];

            // update step
            int step = self.step + 1;

            // wrap around if we reached NUMSTEPS
            if (step >= NUMSTEPS)
                step = 0;

            // store
            self.step = step;

            // time duration until next step
            time = [time dateByAddingTimeInterval:0.5];
        }

        // exit thread
        [NSThread exit];
    }
}
```

This tells me NSTimeInterval is an incompatable type

```
     // time duration until next step
        time = [time dateByAddingTimeInterval: self.tempoControls];
```

Here is where the slider is declared

.m

```
- (IBAction)sliderMoved:(UISlider *)sender
{
    AppDelegate* app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    if (sender == self.tempoSlider)
    {
        PAEControl* tempoControl = app.tempoControls[app.editIndex];
        tempoControl.value = self.tempoSlider.value;
    }
}
```

.h

```
@interface DetailController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *tempoSlider;
- (IBAction)sliderMoved:(UISlider *)sender;
```

Any help would me much appriciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like **self.tempoControls** is an array of **PAEControl** objects. The method named **dateByAddingTimeInterval:** needs an argument of type **NSTimeInterval** (*aka double*). It looks like you're trying to pass in this array instead.

Try changing this line -

```
time = [time dateByAddingTimeInterval: self.tempoControls];
```

To maybe this -

```
PAEControl* tempoControl = self.tempoControls[self.editIndex];
time = [time dateByAddingTimeInterval: (NSTimeInterval)tempoControl.value];
```

*On another note, if this is all running on the main thread, be aware that you are blocking it and the UI will become very unresponsive.*